# How to get Mac Address OR IPv4 address of Client Machine to uniquely identify machine in ASP.net core v3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to perform One Time Password (OTP) device verification when a client logs in from a different machine (just like Google).

In simple words whenever the user changes their device during login it should ask for OTP once per device, so the next time they use that device it should not ask for OTP it should directly ask for the password for the verified device.

Is it possible to get client machine's IP address or mac address in ASP.NET CORE v3.1? I have read various articles on it they suggested to use cookies with usersID & GUID combination. Is there any other way to keep track if user login from different machine or device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is typically handled is by setting a cookie. You check for whether that cookie exists before prompting the user for a second factor. If it does, then the user is good to go, so you skip it.

You cannot do this via MAC address or IP. You cannot get the client's MAC address, because this information is not exposed to the server ever. The IP address is unreliable as it's usually dynamically assigned by the user's ISP and can vary for that user. Additionally, the remote IP can be spoofed, so you should never trust it anyways.